# Make a url clickable gathered from database

Tags: php, html

I have this line of code.

```
<p> Linkedin: <?= $user_info['portfolio_website'] ?></p>
```

The portfolio_website is a database column from user profiles where urls are stored.

Via the code above the urls corresponding to the user is displayed on the website page.

But it's just text and it isn't clickable.

So my question is: How can I make the url clickable?

Comment: is there a reason you're not just putting the url into an href?
`<a href="<?= $user_info['portfolio_website'] ?>">Click Me</a>`

Comment: I think it will look better if the url is visible instead of text because  then the people will now where they will be directed to

Comment: so replace the text with the url as well....

Comment: But the Url's are different its not just one url

Comment: `<?= $user_info['portfolio_website'] ?>` is the url, `<a href="<?= $user_info['portfolio_website'] ?>"> <?= $user_info['portfolio_website'] ?> </a>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By wrapping the url in an anchor tag. Also, you could also hide the url and put any other text to show as the link:

```
<p> Linkedin: 
    <a href="<?= $user_info['portfolio_website'] ?>">
        Some text here
    </a>
</p>
```

To show the url as the clickable link do this:

```
<p> Linkedin: 
    <a href="<?= $user_info['portfolio_website'] ?>">
        <?= $user_info['portfolio_website'] ?>
    </a>
</p>
```

Comment: I tried but it isn't working but thanks for thinking with me

Comment: @john when adding in the href for the anchor, the url may need to be wrapped in single quotes instead of double. I have had code be finicky about that.

Comment: @john there's no reason why this shouldn't work if the `<?=` syntax works for you as posted in question. What's not working?

Comment: With the 'some text here' its working. This text is clickable and direct to the corresponding url. But I want the url to be visible inestead of 'some text here.'

Comment: @john see the update for the clickable url that you want to have as the link.

Comment: @john Glad I could help. If this post answered your question, then please mark it as the accepted answer. Refer to this http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: It may also be noteworthy to avoid using shortcodes "<? " if using with xml (depending on your php version)

Answer (score 1):

It's fairly simple.

Just add an anchor tag and echo out the row within the `href`

Like so:

```
<a href='<?php echo $row['portfolio_website']; ?>'>LinkedIn</a>
```

Alternatively, you could echo the whole anchor tag and just concatenate on the `row`

```
echo '<a href="' . $row['portfolio_website'] . '">LinkedIn</a>';
```

Comment: Or even cleaner, variable expansion within double quotes doesn't need array index quotes, and without a notice `echo "<a href='$row[portfolio_website]'>LinkedIn</a>";`